# Handling screen dim/screen lock in android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a thread running on an activity. And the thread seems to be paused when the screen is off (In wear emulator when you click the power button and lock the screen). How to handle this scenario? 'wakelock' will help? if so how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

That is your problem is that you have a Java Thread running inside an activity UI thread.  Not a good thing to do.  I would either start the thread up and dis-associate it using daemon thread, and keep reference to it in a custom application class or create a service instead.

Fire up the thread with something like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private YourThread thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.thread = new YourThread(this);
        this.thread.setDaemon(true);
        this.thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can handle dimming `onPause()` in your Activity and communicate to the thread (you didn't put any info what kind of thread it is) from there.

However about wakelock I cannot specify on that as I don't have Wear with me to test it. You can use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` for preventing sleeping (dimming screen).